# How can you group a very specfic pattern with regex?

Tags: python, regex

> Problem:

> https://coderbyte.com/editor/Simple%20Symbols

> The str parameter will be composed of + and = symbols with
> several letters between them (ie. ++d+===+c++==a) and for the string
> to be true each letter must be surrounded by a + symbol. So the string
> to the left would be false. The string will not be empty and will have
> at least one letter.

> Input:"+d+=3=+s+"

> Output:"true"

> Input:"f++d+"

> Output:"false"

I'm trying to create a regular expression for the following problem, but I keep running into various problems. How can I produce something that returns the specified rules('+\D+')?

```
import re
plusReg = re.compile(r'[(+A-Za-z+)]')
plusReg.findall()
>>> []
```

Here I thought I could create my own class that searches for the pattern.

```
import re
plusReg = re.compile(r'([\\+,\D,\\+])')
plusReg.findall('adf+a+=4=+S+')
>>> ['a', 'd', 'f', '+', 'a', '+', '=', '=', '+', 'S', '+']
```

Here I thought I the '\\+' would single out the plus symbol and read it as a char.

```
mo = plusReg.search('adf+a+=4=+S+')
mo.group()
>>>'a'
```

Here using the same shell, I tried using the search instead of findall, but I just ended up with the first letter which isn't even surrounded by a plus.

My end result is to group the string 'adf+a+=4=+S+' into ['+a+','+S+'] and so on.

Comment: *So the string to the left would be false* - what does it mean?

Comment: All of the letters in the string have to be surrounded by a + so the string In the question would be false because the last three characters are ==a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to search the string for any letters that are either: (1) *not* preceeded by a `+`, or (2) *not* followed by a `+`. This can be done using look ahead and look behind assertions:

```
>>> rgx = re.compile(r'(?<!\+)[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z](?!\+)')
```

So if `rgx.search(string)` returns `None`, the string is *valid*:

```
>>> rgx.search('+a+') is None
True
>>> rgx.search('+a+b+') is None
True
```

but if it returns a match, the string is *invalid*:

```
>>> rgx.search('+ab+') is None
False
>>> rgx.search('+a=b+') is None
False
>>> rgx.search('a') is None
False
>>> rgx.search('+a') is None
False
>>> rgx.search('a+') is None
False
```

The important thing about look ahead/behind assertions is that they don't consume characters, so they can handle overlapping matches.

Comment: This makes sense, but can you explain to me what you are doing  here (?<!\+)? Specifically the ?<!. And why isn't the < on the other side of the |?

Comment: `(?<!\+)` is a negative look-behind assertion: it means match only if the current character is *not* preceeded by a `+`. Similarly, `(?!\+)`  is a negative look-ahead assertion: it means match only if the current character is *not* followed by a `+`. The "current character" is specified by the pattern `[a-zA-Z]`, which matches a single alphabetic letter. So the whole pattern is trying to find any letter that does *not* have either a `+` before it, or a `+` after it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
import re

def is_valid_str(s):
  return re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', s) == re.findall('\+([a-zA-Z])\+', s)
```

Usage:

```
In [10]: is_valid_str("f++d+")
Out[10]: False

In [11]: is_valid_str("+d+=3=+s+")
Out[11]: True
```

Comment: [This doesn't work when a `+` is surrounded by letters.](http://ideone.com/7ODDQ5)

Comment: Where is that requirement stated?

Comment: `+a+b+` fits the requirements as stated in the problem - it is a string where each letter is surrounded by `+` symbols.

Comment: @Jack. Your test fails if there are overlapping matches.

Comment: Yes, all `re.findall` solutions will probably fail since it only finds non-overlapping matches.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. The regular expression you have is correct, but it can simplify down to just letters:

```
search_pattern = re.compile(r'\+[a-zA-z]\+')
```

for upper and lower case strings. Now we can use this regex with the `findall` function:

```
results = re.findall(search_pattern, 'adf+a+=4=+S+')  # returns ['+a+', '+S+']
```

Now the question needs you to return a boolean depending on if the string is valid to the specified pattern so we can wrap this all up into a function:

```
def is_valid_pattern(pattern_string):
    search_pattern =  re.compile(r'\+[a-zA-z]?\+')
    letter_pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-z]')  # to search for all letters
    results = re.findall(search_pattern, pattern_string)
    letters = re.findall(letter_pattern, pattern_string)
    # if the lenght of the list of all the letters equals the length of all
    # the values found with the pattern, we can say that it is a valid string
    return len(results) == len(letter_pattern)
```

Comment: This will fail if there are overlapping matches.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking for what **isn't** there, as opposed to what **is**. You should search for something like, `([^\+][A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][^\+])`. The `|` in the middle is a logical `or` operator. Then on either side, it checks if it can find *any* scenario where there is a letter without a "+" on the left/right respectively. If if finds something, that means the string fails. If it can't find anything, that means that there are no instances of a letter not being surrounded by "+"'s.

Comment: This will fail if there are overlapping matches.

Comment: By overlapping matches, do you mean for cases such as `"...+a+b+..."`? Or as in `"+abc+"`? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Because in both of these cases, my regex works fine. Overlapping matches shouldn't be an issue for this solution.

Comment: Try it with `+a+b`, `a+b` or `a+b+`, etc.

Comment: I think it's because of the situation in which I'm doing it. My solution breaks not due to "overlapping matches", but because of beginning/end of string match errors.

Comment: In which case your solution with the look-ahead/behind is the next logical step. I need to get used to those more. Thanks for the insight in how to use them

Comment: Yes, you're right - it's not really a problem with overlapping matches. But I think you can fix your pattern by explicitly matching the start/end of the string, like this: `(^|[^\+])[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]([^\+]|$)`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
def SimpleSymbols(str): 
    #added padding, because if str = 'y+4==+r+'
    #then program would return true when it should return false. 
    string = '=' + str + '=' 
    #regex that returns false if a letter *doesn't* have a + in front or back
    plusReg = re.compile(r'[^\+][A-Za-z].|.[A-Za-z][^\+]')
    #if statement that returns "true" if regex doesn't find any letters
    #without a + behind or in front
    if plusReg.search(string) is None:
        return "true"
    return "false"

print SimpleSymbols(raw_input())
```

I borrowed some code from [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41370635/5446749) and Sanjay.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41369550/2) to the question [How can you group a very specfic pattern with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369550/how-can-you-group-a-very-specfic-pattern-with-regex) by the OP [Allen Birmingham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6287355/allen-birmingham) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>